# RDS instance storage limit handling

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am planning using MySQL on RDS instance for my work. I have couple of questions regarding its limit. I checked the below two links but have not clearly understood them :

- [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html)
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html

As per my understanding of link 1 the maximum amount of data that can be stored on single RDS instance is 3TB and based on information in Link 2 the total that be stored across multiple instances is 100 TB. 
Have I understood the above correctly? If so, if my application requires more data to be stored what would be best way to handle? Does creating multiple instances and having different sub-parts of the application deal with its each own separate instance seem a correct way? Or can I still create a single instance(assuming network traffic and data intensive operations are not high) and yet store  more than 3TB data in some other way?

Comment: describe the techie need. what are you doing with this such as relational data or big data or anything you can share that describes the Technical Requirements

Comment: Can't give out much here. Data is will stored in multiple tables however each table will not have huge amounts data.  Type of data stored is different so need multiple tables to store them.

Comment: not trade secrets :>  where does the data reside now, size, performance. What are the technical requirements for mid to low-latency